# Set environment (package?) for eval

Tags: common-lisp

I want to transfer a Lisp form to another host via TCP. For instance it is sent via

`` (prin1 `(setf mypack:*somevar* ,mypack:*somevar*) the-stream) ``.

On the other side the same program is running as on the source side, so all packages exist and such. This quoted form is run through `eval`.
But 'mypack' is neglected by `prin1` so that the variable is set in 'common-lisp-user' package when evaluated.

Is it possible to define the environment, or the package where form is evaluated so that I can set variables, or call functions?

Comment: When the package prefix is not printed, then an option is to make sure that the package prefix IS printed. For example bind the current package to a package which does not use MYPACK, during printing.

Comment: That'd be an option, but how? Using `format`?

Comment: `(let ((cl:*package* (find-package "SOME-OTHER-PACKAGE"))) (print 'foobar:hello))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Printing symbols with and without package prefix**

```
CL-USER 11 > (defpackage "FOO" (:USE ) (:export "X1"))
#<The FOO package, 0/16 internal, 1/16 external>
```

The package `FOO` uses no package and exports the symbol `X1`.

```
CL-USER 12 > (let ((*package* (find-package "CL-USER")))
               (print 'foo:x1)
               (values))

FOO:X1
```

The current package, when printing, is `CL-USER`. The symbol `FOO:X1`   is not accessible in the package `CL-USER` : it is not imported and the package `FOO` is not *used* into `CL-USER`. Thus the symbol `X1` is printed with the package prefix `FOO`. Since the symbol `X1` is exported from package `FOO`, it is printed with one colon as `FOO:X1`.

vs.

```
CL-USER 13 > (let ((*package* (find-package "FOO")))
               (print 'foo:x1)
               (values))

X1
```

Above makes `FOO` the current package during printing. All symbols in this package will be printed without prefix.

**The Common Lisp standard talks about printing package prefixes for symbols**

See [CLHS 22.1.3.3.1 Package Prefixes for Symbols](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_acca.htm).

Also see the various variables controlling the *printer*:  [CLHS 22.1.1.1 Multiple Possible Textual Representations](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_aaa.htm#stdprintercontrolvars)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This works pretty well when setting *package* to like CL-USER which includes none of my symbols.
Again what learned. :)

Comment: @Manfred see also `WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX`, which also binds the current package `*package*` to `CL-USER`.

Comment: You could also set `*package*` to keyword package, then every symbol will have package prefixed name.